# Calling wcf aync service in asp.net core 2.0 while waiting the result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I do understand that I might be getting this wrong since I am porting asp.net application to asp.net core 2.0 (mainly because the optimizations regarding load speed on pages) but I would ask the question anyway.

So my queries are working properly when I am fetching data only, however, I ran into a problem while having to fetch a file path from the database in order to download it on the client side. Since I don't need the whole model of the file I have 3 field dto on the client side that I fill up with the information regarding the file (etc location, size, filename) the problem is that when I send the async request toward the WCF service on Azure that's hold my entity framework link to the database the code continues further without waiting for the data to be retrieved from the database and throws null reference exception while attempting to fill the dto object that is to be sent further to the client in order to retrieve the file that's marked for downloading

This is my data access on the client side

```
 internal async Task<AnimalDocument> GetAnimalDocument(int id)
    {

        var data = await _context.GetAnimalDocumentAsync(id);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnimalDocument>(data);

        return result;
    }
```

And this is where I get the null exception

```
public SeriliazedFile GetFile(int id, int type)
    {
        var result = new SeriliazedFile();
        if (type == 1)
        {
            var data = _context.GetHumanFile(id);
            result.FileName = data.Result.DocumentName;
            result.FilePath = data.Result.DocumentLocation;
            result.FileSize = data.Result.FileSize.Value;
        }
        else if (type == 2)
        {
            var data = _context.GetAnimalDocument(id);
            result.FileName = data.Result.DocumentName;
            result.FilePath = data.Result.DocumentLocation;
            result.FileSize = data.Result.FileSize.Value;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is there a way to force the async request to wait for the result before returning Task that I retrieve from the WCF? I've tried telling _context.GetAnimalDocument(id).Wait(); however, nothing happens it still proceeds further without any result.I've  noticed that the trigger to retrieve the data is fired after the ajax request that is sent toward the page returns 200 causing something like a deadlock but I might be wrong. If anyone could give me a work around it would be nice, I am pretty sure that I would figure it out on my own eventually but time is rare anyway, I hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for posting this, it was not a issue with the WCF or the code in any way, async works perfectly fine with asp.net core 2.0 the issue was with me. I am still adapting to the concept of have [FromBody] in front of the types in the functions, it appears to be that I missed one and I was getting id 0 by default (not that I can figure out why I would get 0 instead of null on integer field when there is no data but that doesn't matter anyway.) in my id field and the data layer was returning null value that's why I was getting null reference exception later.